# I have a partially described gene from a plant, which tool may I use for predicting regolatory and UTRs sequences from a single DNA fragment?

Tags: sequence-annotation, functional-annotation, tools

I have a partially described gene from a plant with CDS and 3'UTR described but no 5'UTR; if I know the locus and upstream and downstream regions, is there a tool I can use for predicting regulatory DNA and UTRs for a given gene?

My annotation data source is the assembly of *Phaseolus vulgaris* [here](https://ftp.ensemblgenomes.org/pub/plants/release-55/gff3/phaseolus_vulgaris/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you need to tell us whether the genome has been sequenced. If not the nearest species with a sequenced genome.

Comment: when you say "partially described" what do you mean? what's the name? Do you have any sources of e.g. GFF3 annotation files, a la M__'s question?

Comment: Hi, sorry, this is my first post here.  So, the plant is Phaseolus vulgaris and is sequenced yet. When I say partially described I mean that I don't have (or can't find) regulatory sequences and in the gff3 file there is not a 5' (the mRNA starts with the first codon). https://ftp.ensemblgenomes.org/pub/plants/release-55/gff3/phaseolus_vulgaris/                    Thank you for the support, I'm new to bioinformatics.

Comment: updating with notes from comments

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you know the gene name, you would be able to look it up in a [transcriptome assembly](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-016-0883-6) presumably, or perhaps [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore) has a full length transcript (search `txid3885[Organism:exp]` with your gene name).

For nearby regulatory DNA, you could consult [an ATAC-seq dataset](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM3674728) or [other similar](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2022.06.15.496248v1.full.pdf), though I doubt that causal links of regulatory DNA to your gene will have been directly assayed.